# DNS not resolved

Tags: dns, web-hosting

I am trying to host a website, I changed to Name servers and all, however I am receiving this error

> The webserver reported that an error occurred while trying to access the website. Please click here to return to the previous page.

Can some body help me on this?
Thank you

Comment: Since the error says that it got a response from the web server the issue is web server related, not DNS related. However please provide more information, like screenshots, exact text, domain name, etc.

Comment: And this is offtopic here as nothing at all related to programming. Try [Webmasters.SE] instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First ensure that the domain is resolving to the IP's you configured, for this you could use tools like [dig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dig_(command)) / [drill](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=drill&sektion=1), or via the web you could use https://intodns.com/

To check the nameservers via command line:

```
$ dig example.com ns +short
```

To check for the 'A' records:

```
$ dig example.com
```

If you just change the nameservers it may take a while for them to be replicated, you can use the `+trace` options:

```
$ dig example.com ns +trace
```

> When tracing is enabled, dig makes iterative queries to resolve the name being looked up. It will follow
>              referrals from the root servers, showing the answer from each server that was used to resolve the lookup.

If that returns the expected results, check your web server configuration.